# ¿Como conecto mi proyecto en .net Core 2.2 con EF a una BD MSSQL en Ionos?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, odbc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Estoy intentando subir una aplicación Web en .net Core 2.2 y EF con una base de datos MSSQL contratando un hosting Windows en Ionos.

Pues bien, se supone que esas bases de datos solo son accesibles desde el hosting así que no puedo probarlo desde mi máquina.

En Ionos nos muestran esta info.
https://www.ionos.es/ayuda/hosting/net/restricciones-para-aplicaciones-aspnet/

¿Quiere decir que no podemos usar variables de entorno en el appsettings?
¿Como conecto mi base de datos al proyecto?

Gracias a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado.

El problema es que en el hosting windows de Ionos, la Base de Datos SQL solo es accesible desde el propio hosting.

*ConnectionString Erroneo:*

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:db000000000.hosting-data.io;Initial 
       Catalog=db000000000;Persist Security Info=False;User 
       ID=dbo000000000;Password=xxxxxxxx"
   }
```

*ConnectionString Correcto:*

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=db000000000.hosting-data.io;Initial 
    Catalog=db000000000;Persist Security Info=False;User 
    ID=dbo000000000;Password=xxxxxxxx"
 }
```

El error estaba que al poner **"tcp:"** debía salir a buscar la BD a internet en vez de buscarla en local. Por lo tanto la bd desde internet era inaccesible por permisos.